# Change tooltip direction when it's out of view

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm trying to change my website's tooltip direction when it's out of the page's viewport, but all I was able to do is to wrap the lines so it doesn't get out of the viewport.

```
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3cjpL14/3/
```

ADD: I'm using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com) by the way..

Comment: Sorry, the JSFiddle is [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/x3cjpL14/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just disabled line wrapping on the tooltip by using the `white-space` in the css file and then checked if the tooltip isn't visible by the jQuery `$("#element").visible()` and changed positions with css from the JS file :)